# How to seeking mp4 video realtime with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I am moving my android application from MediaPlayer to ExoPlayer.

When I use MediaPlayer I can easier seek real-time the video. I mean when video playing then I drag the seek bar -> then the screen will respond immediately (When I finish dragged then video play). But when moving to ExoPlayer, I can't do it. The video only renders when I finish dragged action, It seems not smooth as MediaPlayer.

Another problem is when I change Surface for ExoPlayer, It delays some seconds for mp4 video (Default MediaPlayer does not display)

Please tell me what I am wrong.

**Note:**

- I run the sample from https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer.
- I also checked issue [#667 from github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/677)

The screenshot to explain my problem.
[image: need finish dragged to seek video]

Comment: A quick note on the difference between local video on the device and a streamed video - if it is a streamed video then you generally are reliant on a 'track' of thumbnails being available to support the seeking as the video is only downloaded in chunks, so if you skip ahead it won't have that chunk yet. This is just a FYI comment - your question re observed different experience between MediaPlayuer and ExoPlayer is good and still stands.

Comment: First, Thank you so much. In my case, I use live video streaming. For me, I think ExoPlayer is more advanced than MediaPlayer. So I think what can do in MediaPlayer can do in ExoPlayer. I thought the problem is in the config.